# MVC design question

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing

Just a note, I'm new to MVC.

I'm trying to make my code as much decoupled and testable as possible.
I have a view with a text box and button.
I want to enable the button when a new text is entered and respects a certain criteria.

Ideally, I'd like this logic that decides if the button is enabled or not outside the view so it can be unit tested.

My understanding of MVC goes like that:
In my View I have a reference to my Controller.
In my Controller I have a reference to my Model.
In my Model I have a reference to my View.

Can you tell me if the following is a good design.
I added a boolean to the model buttonEnabled.
the sequence of event is like that: 
Text is input in the text box, the text box has a listener. The listener calls a textChanged method on the Controller, the controller does the checks on whether to enable the button or not, and then sets the buttonEnabled of the Model through a setButtonEnabled accessor.
The accessor changes the value of buttonEnabled, and calls a buttonEnabledChanged() on the view (which exposes that method)
the idea is that the view is specific observer of the model, and the model is an observable which could theoretically have multiple views, and can call buttonEnabledChanged() on all of them.

Please let me know what you think.

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072979).

Comment: In the context you describe, I would rather use MVP (P, the Presenter, would contain the logic for enabling the button) instead of MVC.

Comment: In my view, the answer above is defeating the purpose of separation, although is a good explanation. But the example is too tightly coupled to the GUI to the point where it's impossible to unit test.

Answer (score 1):

This is a philosophical answer to a philosophical question :)

What you suggest could be correct.  But the real question is if `buttonEnabled` is really a good candidate for your model.  It's a purely gui thing and makes no sense being there.  Thing that are really specific to the interface belong in the view, and nowhere else.

Now there might be a reason that the button is disabled (like, entry is not valid).  Then you could just give it another name in the model (`isValid`).  The translation from `!isValid` to `!buttonEnabled` would then become part of the controller, or even the view itself.

But I'm guessing that, in your case, the only reason to block the button when there is no content is to make it less likely for the user to send in a blank form.  In that case, I would do the check in view completely (javascript if it's web), just for user convenience.  In the model, just throw an exception (`IllegalArgumentException` seems likely) if the empty string gets there anyway.

If you're unit-testing your model, it makes a lot more sense to test if it will complain about an empty string, then to check if your model is setting `buttonEnabled` to false.  If you really want to test gui functionality, there are solutions for that (for web, selenium comes to mind).

Answer (score 1):

What you suggest is overcomplicated and, in my opinion, wrong from the standpoint of MVC.

- The controller should not check whether or not to enable button, it is the task of model.
- The model should not call any methods on view.
- You have too specific methods. This desire to update only specific stuff, like buttonEnabledChanged() will make things overcomplicated in future, where components depend on each other through some business logic.

What you need is to bind this text box's value to model value, perhaps through the controller. So, changing text boxes value will change model's value. It should then call the update on the view. The view knows, that in the model there is some property that determines if the button should be enabled. It shouldn't be called isButtonEnabled() because it is agnostic of the view. It should be called isTextMatchingCriteria or something. Based on the value of that property, the view decides whether to enable the button or not.

This way:

- Controller only controlls. It is catches and delegates, updates, but doesn't decide anything on business logic.
- The model is independent of view.
- View doesn't have any specific methods that can be called separately. The only thing it can is to render a correct presentation based on the current state of the model. It also specifies, what one or another state of the model mean on the screen - a disabled button or error message. The model shouldn't do that.

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around what you wrote above, I have a few questions: "Controller doesn't decide on business logic", I thought it does, where should I put the business logic? in the Model? I thought the model only holds the data. Also you said "the Model should not call any methods on view" how else can we update the view when the model changes? you then say "it should then call the update on the view", I thought you were talking about the model, so th model call the update method on the view after all, no?

Comment: @Charbel the "link" from the Model to the View is generally done through the goold old Observer pattern (or Swing Listeners which are the same), or through data binding. The Model provides the necessary methods for observers (the View) to register themselves. Hence the Model doesn't need to "know" the View.